# WPF Style All Controls in One Instance UserControl

Tags: wpf

Is it possible to have say one UserControl with couple of Controls on it, but when reusing the UserControl to only apply on some of the a style or template for all those controls?

For example local:UserControl1 Grid.Column="1"'s Controls have a style/template applied?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <local:UserControl1  />
    <local:UserControl1 Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not selectively apply a style based on some condition of the styled control without implementing an according behavior. Still, you can achieve the same thing with style triggers. You can set the template of the control in a style trigger, so applying a certain template based on some condition of the templated control is possible with out of the box features. In the example the background is set selectively:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <!-- Defining the TargetType but no x:Key will apply the style
        to ALL children of this grid of the specified type -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:UserControl1}">
            <Style.Triggers>                    
                <Trigger Property="Grid.Column" Value="1">
                    <!-- All setters here get applied only when 
                    trigger condition is met -->
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <local:UserControl1  />
    <local:UserControl1 Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```